# How does other functions access 'goal' value that was generated in get_goal function?

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to make the 'goal' value accessable to other functions like 'display_instructions' and 'gameLoop'.

But when I run the program, it says 'goal' is not define in other functions

I have tried add 
    goal = get_goal()
to display_instruction() and it seems to work

but does work out trying to do the same to gameLoop

because it gives me an error of int()< function()

```
import random

def main():

    goal = get_goal()
    display_instruction(goal)
    userInput()
    gameLoop(goal)
    playAgain()

def get_goal():
    goal = random.randint(1, 99)
    return goal

def userInput():
    inputNum = input('Enter a valid coin value: ')
    return inputNum

def display_instruction(goal):

    instruction = ['Game Session Starts'
               'Enter coins values as 1-penny, 5-nickel, 10-dime, and 25-quarter.',
               'Enter coins that add up to ' + str(goal) + ' cents, one per line.']    
    for lines in instruction:
        print(lines)

def gameLoop(goal):
    totalInput = 0
    while totalInput < goal:
        try:

            inputNum = userInput()

        if inputNum == "":
            print("Session Ends!")
            ValueError

        elif int(inputNum) in [1, 5, 10, 25]:

            totalInput += int(inputNum)

        else:

            print("Invalid entry - Try again!")
            continue
    except ValueError:

        print("Invalid entry - Try again!")
        continue
    print("Game Session Ends")
    print("Here is the outcome : ")
    if goal == totalInput:
        print("Success!")
    elif totalInput < goal:
        diff = goal - totalInput

        print("Failure - you only entered "+str(totalInput)+" cents")
        print("You are short of "+str(diff)+" cents")
    else:
        diff = totalInput - goal
        print("Failure - you entered "+str(totalInput)+" cents")
        print("The amount exceeds "+str(goal)+" cents by "+str(diff)+" cents")

def playAgain():

    secondRun = input("Play another game session (y/n)?")
    if secondRun == 'y' or secondRun == 'Y':
        main()
    else:
        print("thanks for playing... Good Bye!")    






main()
```

I try to make it run as a game. By adding the input values to match the random generated number'goal'

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass goal to the functions you desire.

def main():

```
get_goal()
display_instruction()
```

can be

```
def main():

    goal = get_goal()
    display_instruction(goal)
    gameLoop(goal)
```

The functions display_instruction and gameLoop should be defined as:

```
def display_instruction(goal):
    #Rest of the function code.

def gameLoop(goal):
    #Rest of the function code.
```

---

Solution as per getting the goal in gameLoop and as discussed with OP

**Note:** The below code only contains relavant portions where there was an error. OP should just try to take this reference and try to correct the program in question.

```
import random

def get_goal():
    goal = random.randint(1, 99)
    return goal

def userInput():
    inputNum = raw_input('Enter a valid coin value. ')
    return inputNum

def gameLoop():
    totalInput = 0
    goal = get_goal()
    print ("Goal = "+str(goal))

    while totalInput < goal:
        inputNumStr = userInput()
        if inputNumStr == "":
           print ("Session Ends")
           break

        inputNum = int(inputNumStr)

        if inputNum not in [1,5,10,25]:
            print("Invalid Entry - Try Again")
            continue
        else:
            totalInput += inputNum

    print("Game Session Ends")
    print("Here is the outcome : ")
    if goal == totalInput:
        print("Success!")
    elif totalInput < goal:
        diff = goal - totalInput
        print("Failure - you only entered "+str(totalInput)+" cents")
        print("You are short of "+str(diff)+" cents")
    else:
        diff = totalInput - goal
        print("Failure - you entered "+str(totalInput)+" cents")
        print("The amount exceeds "+str(goal)+" cents by "+str(diff)+" cents")

gameLoop()
```

Comment: it worked, thank you. But there is another issue with my code. somehow it will skip  the first input for some reason. could you please take a look?

Comment: I don't think this would work. Integers are immutable, so when you passed it into display_instruction, it would display a different value then would be used in gameLoop. (Because he changes the value in display_instruction.)

Comment: i sort it out by deleting the userInput in main(). thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems I have figured it out by adding the following code to gameLoop:

```
goal = get_goal()
goalstr = str(goal)
```

and change the 
    while totalInput < goal
to 
    totalInput < int(goal)

bth,it looks stupid.

Comment: Please delete this. You can't post queries in the Answer Section.